# btns (as anchor tags) not at same height but is side by side

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have two buttons that need to sit side by side.  I got that.  But the right 'button' is sitting higher than the left one.  Why?  I believe that it is because of my right 'button' has two lines of text with it.  My proponent will not budge on this button having two lines of text.  Does anyone know how to do this better?

I put my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/energeticpixels/k7awcfts/

Here is my code:

```
<div id='tonyzBTNs'>
            <a id='regCourse' class='btn' href='https://cloudlms.slhc.serco-na.com' target='_blank'>Register for Course</a>
            <a id='regTest' class='btn' href='https://www.atrrs.army.mil/atrrscc/courseInfo.aspx?fy=2016&amp;sch=910&amp;crs=4E-F33%2f645-F17+(DL)&amp;crstitle=ARMY+ELECTRICAL+EXPLOSIVE+SAFETY+(CERT)&amp;phase=' target='_blank'>Register for Exam<span style="font-size: 10px;"><br />(after completing the course)</span></a>
        </div>
```

And the css:

```
#tonyzBTNs {
              margin-top: 20px;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            #tonyzBTNs .btn {
              text-align: center;
              font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              font-size: 18px;
              font-weight: bold;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
            #tonyzBTNs #regCourse {
              background-color: #9EB95C;
              border: 2px solid #708542;
              border-radius: 10px;
              padding: 10px;
              color: black;
            }
            #tonyzBTNs #regTest {
              background-color: #C54F4D;
              border: 2px solid #6A4346;
              border-radius: 10px;
              padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
              color: white;
              display: inline-block;
            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#tonyzBTNs .btn {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/k7awcfts/2/)**

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? This achieves the objective as I understand it.

Comment: Yah, I also tried to kill the padding-top on that second 'button', but wasn't able to make it work.  Thanks for the great suggestion on vertical-align setting!!  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the rest of the site is layed out, Using `float: left;` in your `#tonyzBTNs #regCourse` will probably solve your issue.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7awcfts/3/)